# Grafana from docker image: can't enter grafana homepage at localhost

Tags: docker, grafana

I successfully run Grafana-server from image.
Docker-compose:

```
version: '2.1'

   services:

      grafana:
        image: grafana/grafana:6.7.2
        container_name: grafana
        ports:
        - '3000:5432'
```

Last entry of log output:

```
HTTP Server Listen    logger=http.server address=[::]:3000 protocol=http subUrl= socket=
```

But I can't enter in Grafana-IU at http://localhost:3000.   Error: "Cant connect to server localhost"

Comment: `http://localhost:3000`?

Comment: Yes, its a mistake in my Ask, of course - http://localhost:3000.   But the essence does not change - Error retains.

Comment: Why would you map Grafana port to PostgreSQL?

Comment: I'm able to build Grafana dashboards, using data from PostgreSQL database.  And PostgreSQL is not deployed at container, but at host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the Grafana image listens on port 3000, so you need to map port 3000 to whatever port you want to use on the host. If you want to use port 3000 like it looks like from what you've tried, both port numbers should be 3000 like this

```
version: '2.1'

   services:

      grafana:
        image: grafana/grafana:6.7.2
        container_name: grafana
        ports:
        - '3000:3000'
```

Comment: Yes, it is a solution! And one more moment: could I map ones more Grafana port to PostgreSQL port in this case? Does Grafana has only one allowed port (3000 as a default)?